# animation-iteration-count infinte not working on Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari

I've got an animation for a shaking submit button that repeats itself. It works on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but on Safari, the repeating doesn't work.

It seems that the animation-iteration-count isn't working. I've tried it with a number and with infinity.

Here is my CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {
     animation-name:shake;
     animation-duration:5s;
     animation-timing-function:ease-in;
     animation-delay:3s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -moz-animation-name:shake;
     -moz-animation-duration:5s;
     -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
     -moz-animation-delay:3s;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-name:shake;
     -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
     -webkit-animation-delay:3s;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes shake {
        0% {left: 0}
        1% {left: -3px}
        2% {left: 5px}
        3% {left: -8px}
        4% {left: 8px}
        5% {left: -5px}
        6% {left: 3px}
        7% {left: 0}
        100% {left:0}
    }
    @-moz-keyframes shake {
        0% {left: 0}
        1% {left: -3px}
        2% {left: 5px}
        3% {left: -8px}
        4% {left: 8px}
        5% {left: -5px}
        6% {left: 3px}
        7% {left: 0}
        100% {left:0}
    }
    @keyframes shake {
        0% {left: 0}
        1% {left: -3px}
        2% {left: 5px}
        3% {left: -8px}
        4% {left: 8px}
        5% {left: -5px}
        6% {left: 3px}
        7% {left: 0}
        100% {left:0}
    }
```

do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Works for me on Safari 12. Note that, even though that's apparently not the issue here, you should place the spec compliant rules at the bottom, so they are the ones selected by supporting browsers.

Comment: I meant safari for iOS, sorry should've mentioned that